# Amazon SQS service with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I am fairly new to Amazon SQS and I am having a hard time understanding what is going on. I set the HTTP Path to a file that could handle the requests. but I am not sure if that was the correct thing to do. What is the proper way? Why do the messages go directly to "In Flight"? What happens when the message is sent to the HTTP path? I am using php for my application, so if someone could give me guidance on what I am doing wrong, then I would greatly appreciate it!

When I check for a message with my php script that looks likes this:

```
$sqs_client = new SqsClient($sqs_credentials);

// Get the queue URL from the queue name.
$result = $sqs_client->getQueueUrl(array('QueueName' => "NormalPoll"));
$queue_url = $result->get('QueueUrl');

// Receive a message from the queue
$result = $sqs_client->receiveMessage(array(
    'QueueUrl' => $queue_url
));

if ($result['Messages'] == null) {
    die('No Message');
}

// Get the message information
$result_message = array_pop($result['Messages']);
$body = $result_message['Body'];
print $body;
```

I always get 'No Message' in return when running the program. I inserted a message via the AWS SQS console and I am unable to receive it. The message goes automatically to 'in flight'.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: If they are in-flight then your Elastic Beanstalk application is consuming the messages. If the application isn't processing the messages properly then you should add some logging to your application to determine why it is failing.

Comment: When I attempt to receive the message with my application, there is no message. My application doesn't run before the message is already received. This situation is very weird to me.

Comment: Can you stop the beanstalk consumer and try?

Comment: How do I go about doing this? I have searched Elastic Beanstalk for the past couple days and have not seen a place to stop the consumer.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Are you using a Beanstalk Worker Environment with an SQS queue configured? Or are you just using a Beanstalk Web Environment with some custom SQS code?

Comment: I am using the Beanstalk Worker Environment with a SQS queue configured.

Comment: Since you are using a Beanstalk Worker Environment with an SQS queue configured, Elastic Beanstalk is going to automatically take every message in the queue and send it to the endpoint you have configured. This is why the messages are in-flight as soon as you create them, because they have been sent to your server already.

Comment: How do I go about consuming them?

Comment: Your endpoint is being sent the contents of the messages, you need to write some code that runs at that endpoint to process the messages. I can't tell you exactly how to do that since that seems highly dependent on exactly what you are trying to accomplish with your application. In general you need to read the contents of the messages from the HTTP request being posted to your endpoint.

Comment: @Robert, I would advice you to read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html

Comment: Do I get the information via a HTTP POST? if so, in php I use the $_POST variable? I just want something the gets the data from the "Body" of the http request. Does the file at the endpoint need to have a specific naming convention?

Comment: Yes you get the information via HTTP post. No the "file" doesn't need a specific naming convention, since you aren't even specifying a "file" you are specifying a URL. Please read the documentation instead of asking us to read it for you.

Comment: The documentation clearly says sqsd will submit a POST request to your app.

Comment: I am getting a 500 error when attempting to use it. I created an index.php file and started to look at the logs a lot more often. I still have no idea what the possible problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messages are inflight because of the beanstalk worker environment configuration.
The following documentation provides details on how to configure a beanstalk worker environment.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html

Comment: I do not have a configured SNS for the queue. Where should I point the endpoint? Sorry for asking noobish questions. I am new to AWS.

Comment: I was thinking you are using the subscribe queue to sns topic configuration. I did not see the code snippet earlier. Can you confirm when the php script is not running and you donot have view/delete window open on aws console the messages are still going into inflight?

Comment: All the messages are still going in flight. Should I configure an SNS?

Comment: No. I think there is some other consumer running somewhere? Is this a new queue you created? Also check if there are any php script instances running in the background.

Comment: I created the queue recently, so it is kind of new. there are not any other php scripts running in the background.

Comment: Weird. When your script is not running, messages should not go into flight.  Are you viewing the messages on AWS console? you said you added them using SQS console.

Comment: No, I do not view them using the console. Where could the messages possibly be going? Does AWS have a cron job running?

Comment: He specifically said in the question that he had configured an ElasticBeanstalk consumer for the queue. This has nothing to do with SNS.

Comment: Beanstalk, interesting..i missed that part in question header, did not see it in the description. Robert can you confirm that?